# maximal subgroup of a $p$-group

Tags: finite-groups

Let $G$ be a $p$-group of order $p^t$, and also let $exp(G)=p$. Is there such a group $G$, such that every maximal subgroups of it, not being abelian? In fact, I want an example of such a group with smallest order, smallest $t$.

Comment: For $p$ odd, a non-Abelian extra special group of order $p^{2n+1}$ and exponent $p$ has no Abelian subgroup of order greater than $p^{n+1}.$ Hence if $n >1,$ then none of its maximal subgroups are Abelian. So there are examples of order $p^{5}$ for any odd prime $p.$ I am not sure whether these have minimal order.

Comment: Thank you of your answer. Would you please tell me where can I find the proof of what you say, "For $p$ odd, a non-Abelian extra special group of order $p^{2n}+1 and exponent $p$ has no Abelian subgroup of order greater than $p^n+1$"?

Comment: Once you understand http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extra_special_group it is not too hard.

Answer (score 2):

To complete my comment: For $p$ an odd prime, a non-Abelian extra special group $P$ of order $p^{2n+1}$ and exponent $p$ has no Abelian subgroup of order greater than $p^{n+1}$. Hence if n>1, then none of its maximal subgroups are Abelian. So there are examples of order $p^{5}$ for any odd prime p.

There are no smaller examples of exponent $p,$ for if $Q$ is a $p$-group of exponent $p$ and order $p^{4}$, an Abelian normal subgroup $A$ of $Q$ of order $p^{2}$ is not maximal Abelian, for if it were, then $C_{Q}(A) = A$ and $Q/A$ is isomorphic to a $p$-subgroup of ${\rm Aut}(A).$
However, ${\rm Aut}(A) \cong {\rm GL}(2,p),$ which does not have order divisible by $p^{2}.$ Hence $Q$ does contain an Abelian maximal subgroup.